# Restrict SSH Forward Tunneling Destination By User

Tags: linux, ssh

Can the SSH Forward tunneling destination be restricted on a per user basis?

Example: client 'a' can forward tunnel to 192.168.10.2:22 - only. Client 'b' can forward tunnel to 192.168.11.2:22 - exclusively.

### **Update**

I'm looking to restrict the following tunneling command, on a per user or per group basis:

---

*Requirements:*

- client_a can forward tunnel to 192.168.10.*, exclusive.
- client_b can forward tunnel to 192.168.11.*, exclusive.

*Valid tunneling command (for client_a):*

```
ssh -f client_a@gateway -L localhost:2222:192.168.10.2:22 -N
```

*Invalid tunneling command (for client_a) - SSH connection on gateway should close immediately.*

```
ssh -f client_a@gateway -L localhost:2222:192.168.11.2:22 -N
```

*Valid tunneling command (for client_b):*

```
ssh -f client_b@gateway -L localhost:2222:192.168.11.2:22 -N
```

*Invalid tunneling command (for client_b) - SSH connection on gateway should close immediately.*

```
ssh -f client_b@gateway -L localhost:2222:192.168.10.2:22 -N
```

---

Can this restriction be achieved with modifications to the *sshd_config*?

Comment: Why the down vote, it's a reasonable question.

Comment: More details would be useful. Are you talking about **LocalForward** / **RemoteForward** or the `Tunnel` [configuration option](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config)? (e.g. **Tunnel** Request tun(4) device forwarding between the client and the server. The argument must be ''yes'', ''point-to-point'' (layer 3), ''ethernet'' (layer 2), or ''no''.)

Comment: I've added clarification. I already have a configuration in place to only allow tunneling, users cannot log into the gateway and obtain a session - the shell is set to /bin/false, and only TcpPortForwarding is allowed. I would like to restrict which servers they can tunnel via the gateway to; e.g. client_n is restricted to a particular sub-net of servers, which are assigned to client_n. If a client attempts to establish a tunnel to a server which he has not been granted access to - the gateway should immediately terminate the connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming its a modern sshd version, [/etc/ssh/sshd_config](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sshd_config(5)) supports the `Match` and `PermitOpen` directives, which can be combined to restrict the targets specified by clients setting [LocalForward](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) options

> **PermitOpen**
>           Specifies the destinations to which TCP port forwarding is permitted.  The forwarding specification must be one of the following forms:
>
> ```
>           PermitOpen host:port
>           PermitOpen IPv4_addr:port
>           PermitOpen [IPv6_addr]:port
> ```
>
> Multiple forwards may be specified by separating them with whites-
>            pace.  An argument of “any” can be used to remove all restrictions
>            and permit any forwarding requests.  By default all port forwarding requests are permitted.
>   https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sshd_config(5)

So something like this should work...

```
Match User client_a
    PermitOpen none
    PermitOpen 192.168.10.2:22

Match User client_b
    PermitOpen none
    PermitOpen 192.168.11.2:22
```

I am not 100% sure of the ordering of those PermitOpens.. (`By
         default all port forwarding requests are permitted.`) so you might have to reverse them, or add a `Permit none` at the appropriate point to block unmatched forwardings.

Or possibly like this;

```
Match User client_a
    PermitOpen 192.168.10.2:22

Match User client_b
    PermitOpen 192.168.11.2:22

Match User client_a client_b
    PermitOpen none
```